# Merging two queries to one JSON object

Tags: php, json, merge

I have two queries:

```
1) $result = $this->_db->get_where("wishes",array("is_open"=>1))->result_array();
2) $requirements_result = $this->_db->get("requirements")->result_array();
```

I'm trying to output the data in this JSON format:

```
{
    [
      {
        id:12,
        title:"Meet Messi",
        image_url:"http://dsadsa.dsadsa",
        previewImageUrl:"http://kdjfla.com"
        is_open:"true"
        requirements: [
      {
        id: 123,
        title:"kiss Messi",
        is_complete: true
      }
    ]
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

I created two models (one for each query).
This is what I've done so far:

```
$result = $this->_db->get_where("wishes",array("is_open"=>1))->result_array();
$requirements_result = $this->_db->get("requirements")->result_array();

$return_array = array();
foreach ($result as $value)
{                   
    $wishes_model = new wishes_model(); 
    $wishes_model->init_wishes($value);
    $return_array[] = $wishes_model;
}
return $return_array;
```

How to i insert the requirements result to create this JSON?

Comment: What is that database API? You need to write a `JOIN`, does it provide a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, i can write a JOIN.
The problem is organized it in this JSON format

Comment: Loop over the results. If the `wishes` ID is the same as the previous one, add the `requirements` columns to the `requirements` array. If not, add a new `wishes` element to `$return_array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create your `wishes` array as an associative array, with the ID as the key:

```
$wishes_array = array();
foreach ($results as $value) {
    $wishes_model = new wishes_model();
    $wishes_model->init_wishes($value);
    $wishes_array[$value['id']] = $wishes_model;
}
```

Then you can add the requirements to the appropriate wish:

```
foreach ($requirements_results as $req) {
    $wishes_array[$req['wish_id']]->requirements[] = $req;
}
```

I'm making some assumptions about which things in your application are associative arrays versus objects. You should be able to adjust this to match your specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Hi like you have 2 results say result1 and result2

you can make 2 foreach loop for each and store them in two different array and then
you make pass it in result and encode it.

see how it works:

```
foreach ($result1 as $res)
{
    $result_s1[]=$res;
}
foreach($result2 as $cmd)
{
   result_s1[]=$cmd;
}
$resultdata[]=array_merge($result_s1,$result_s2)
```

Comment: This won't give the kind of results he wants. `requirements` should be an element of the corresponding `wishes` element.

Answer (score 0):

I have couple of question but for now i am gonna guess.
You can try [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) but it will overwrite same keys.
If you don't want that you can add prefix to keys and then merge both array.

And i think rest of the solutions you already have in here.